# PHP shell_exec() wait and curl asynchronously and stay after exit()

Tags: php, shell, curl, exec, telegram

I'm developing a simple game on `Telegram` (which has its response timeout), wrote with PHP OOP.
I was looking for something like `shell_exec("sleep 60; curl https://mywebsite.com/page.php?param=code")` `(or wget is fine as well)`.

I mean, wait some defined time and then open that page to do some stuff. I've already tried with `nohup`, with >/dev/null 2>/dev/null and with & in the end of the `cmd (and even all together)`; but happens that PHP waits for response or exiting from PHP (executed all the code), terminates the launched shell as well (nothing happens in frontend).

How can I avoid this behaviour? I just want to bypass stupid loops running on my server just to use the server when needed.

I can also add that I cannot install gnome-terminal and I've also tried with "screen". I've not tried using `sudo` in front but I'm pretty sure PHP has not that right.

Comment: Can you explain a little better what are you trying to achieve? Don't make much sense to run a wait in a `shell_exec` call. Can't you use the PHP native functions for [sleep](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sleep.php) and [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php)?

Comment: As I told, there’s a Telegram timeout of 30 seconds. I could have 60s, 90s, 120s of wait and then stop the round. I cannot use the sleep() function in PHP because I’ll exceed timeout and I cannot extend it because it’s due to Telegram.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with curl -m

from curl manpage

```
   -m, --max-time <time>
          Maximum time in seconds that you allow the whole operation to take.  This is useful for preventing your batch jobs
          from  hanging  for hours due to slow networks or links going down.  Since 7.32.0, this option accepts decimal val‐
          ues, but the actual timeout will decrease in accuracy as the specified timeout increases in decimal precision.
```

Comment: This is not was I looking for.. Thanks anyway!